# Null pointer and index out of bounds on ArrayList and Map

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception, maps, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class DataStorage implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5597052819894601310L;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, String[]> nameMap;
private int index = 0;

DataStorage() {
    array.add(index, new ArrayList<String>());
}
public void addDataToRow() {
    index += 1;
    array.add(index, new ArrayList<String>());
    array.get(index).add(new String());
}

public void addDataToColumn(int pos, String data) {
    array.get(index).add(pos, data);
}

public int rowSize() {
    return array.size();
}

public int colSize() {
    return array.get(index).size();
}

public String initNameMap() {
    nameMap = new TreeMap<>();
    String out = "";
    for(int i = 2; i < array.size(); i++) {
        String[] infoHolder = new String[40];
        String name = array.get(i).get(2);
        int index = 0;
        for(int w = 3; w < array.get(i).size(); w++) {
            System.out.println(index);
            infoHolder[index] = array.get(i).get(w);
            index++;
        }
        nameMap.put(name, infoHolder);
    }

    for(String x : nameMap.keySet()) out += x + "\n";
    return out;

}

public String navigateArray(int rStart, int cStart) {
    String out = "";
    for(int i = rStart; i < array.size(); i++) {
        for(int w = cStart; w < array.get(i).size(); w++) {
            out += array.get(i).get(w) + " ";
        }
        out += "\n";
    }
    return out;
}

}
```

So this is what is happening. I have the class that I have included in this question. I created and object of this class and populated the ArrayList in this class with information from a file, then I serialized the object. Later on, I added the initNameMap() method, and added a Map initialized as a TreeMap. Now, I have deserialized the object I serialized before, and I can retrieve the information in it, but when I call the initNameMap() method it gives me the following exceptions:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 at this segment of code:

```
String name = array.get(i).get(2);
```

and a java.lang.NullPointerException at this segment of code:

```
nameMap.put(name, infoHolder);
```

I simply do not understand why this is happening. It is extremely confusing for me, specially the indexoutofbounds exception. Could anyone explain this to me? Does it have anything to do with the serialization? Thanks

Comment: So you serialized an object of this class, changed the class, then  deserialized the previous version using the new version?  I haven't studied that, but I wouldn't think serialization would support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.get(i).get(2);
```

The nested ArrayList in

```
array
```

has a size of 1, so when you try to get the 2nd element(which doesn't exist) you are getting the OutOfBoundsException.

```
name
```

will be null as a result. You need to figure out why the nested ArrayList in array does not have two elements as expected.

Comment: That's what I explained was not possible, it should not have a size of  1. If I run array.get(i).get(2) inside of navigateArray() it does not give me that error but instead outputs the data I stored. I don't know why it is behaving like that.

Comment: array is obviously being modified in the interim then. Could you post some more code where you are instantiating DataStorage?

Comment: The only thing I do with DataStore is deserialize the object I previously serialized and then I call initNameMap(). Then it gives me those exceptions. If I call navigateArray() it displays the data properly. This is where I call them:
    String out = storer.navigateArray(0, storer.rowSize(), 0, 29);
    storer.initNameMap();
    jTextArea1.setText(out);

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. You say storer.navigateArray(0, storer.rowSize(), 0, 29); but navigateArray only has two parameters in the code you originally posted ( navigateArray(int rStart, int cStart) )

Comment: Sorry about, I'm currently testing different things and I modified that method, but whether it is storer.navigateArray(0, storer.rowSize(), 0, 29); or storer.navigateArray(0, storer.rowSize(), 0); I don't think makes much difference or does it? This is how I deserialize it if it helps: try {
   java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("storer.ser");
   java.io.ObjectInputStream ois = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(fis);
   storer = (DataStorage) ois.readObject();
   ois.close();
  } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: And for now that's everything I'm doing with DataStorage

Comment: It's really hard to say with what you have posted. Check that array has two elements in the nested ArrayList before you serialize it and and then immediately deserialize it and check array to see that it's the same. It should be, since ArrayList is serializeable. My guess is that you are modifying array in some other code that is not shown.